# Convey 'is raised' in mathematical context

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques, science

> The degree of the equation is the power to which the
> highest derivative is raised.

Deepl conveys this as

> Le degré de l'équation est la puissance à laquelle la dérivée la plus élevée est élevée.

To avoid the 'élévée' I said

> Le degré de l'équation est la puissance à laquelle on met la dérivée la plus élevée.

I think there are better ways. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le degré de l'équation est la puissance à laquelle la dérivée de plus grand ordre est élevée

Answer (score 3):

You could also use:

- *Le degré de l'équation est la puissance à laquelle la dérivée la plus **haute** est élevée.*

It allows to avoid the repetition of *élevée*, and all mathematician readers will understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a plusieurs formulations de cet état de chose.

- Le degré de l'équation est la puissance de la dérivée du plus grand ordre.
- Le degré de l'équation est la puissance de la dérivée qui donne son ordre. de l'équation (différentielle).
- Le degré de l'équation est la puissance de la dérivée qui donne l'ordre de l'équation (différentielle).

Le degré d'une équation différentielle n'est pas une caractéristique dont on se soucie trop en France et un certain nombre de références qui traitent de ces équations ne le mentionnent pas, se bornant à fournir une définition de l'ordre. Cependant, ce degré, quand il est défini, peut ne pas l'être comme dans les mathématiques anglo-saxonnes, c'est à dire que sa définition peut être celle-ci.

- Le degré d'une équation différentielle ordinaire E(x,f,f',f'',…f⁽ⁿ⁾)=0 est défini comme étant la plus grande des puissances auxquelles sont élevées la fonction (y) et ses dérivées. Donc, selon cette définition le degré de y''+ y³ + x(y')²=0 est 3, alors qu'il est 1 selon l'autre définition.
  (*p. 722, Toutes les Mathématiques et les bases de l'Informatique, Horst Stöcker Ed. Dunod 2002*)

---

> Le degré de l'équation est la puissance à laquelle on met la dérivée la plus élevée.

Cette façon d'écrire la définition n'est pas idiomatique; elle est gauche. "Mettre" n'est pas employé dans les textes dans ce contexte. Ensuite, une fonction ou dérivée n'est jamais dite être *élevée* à un ordre; on dit toujours "*une dérivée d'ordre n*" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e+d%27ordre&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e%20d%27%20ordre%3B%2Cc0)).

- Le degré de l'équation est la puissance à laquelle se trouve la dérivée d'ordre le plus élevée/Le plus haut.